# Date sent from angular to API is one day behind

Tags: angular, typescript, date, datepicker, mat-datepicker

I have a form where i send a date and when it is received in the API is one day behind.

Here is my html template:

```
<div class="container">
<form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Start date</mat-label>
        <input name="rentalstartdate" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" #startdate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.rentalstartdate" required>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="service.formData.rentalstartdate.touched && !service.formData.rentalstartdate.valid">Start date is required</div>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>End date</mat-label>
        <input name="rentalenddate" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" #enddate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.rentalenddate" required>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="service.formData.rentalenddate.touched && !service.formData.rentalenddate.valid">End date is required</div>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Book a car</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is my method in component.ts where i call the service method:

```
 onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  this.CreateReservation(form);
 }

 CreateReservation(form: NgForm) {
this.service.CreateReservation().subscribe(
  res => {
    this.resetForm(form);
  },
  err => {
  }
 )
}
```

And here is my service.ts

```
formData: Reservation;

CreateReservation() {
return this.http.post(this.rootURL + '/reservation/createreservation', this.formData);
}
```

How can i send the date without being one day behind?

Comment: Please show the incorrect date being entered and check the timezone on the server.

Comment: This is because you select the date on UI as per your current time zone but when it goes to API it will automatically gets converted to UTC (GTM +00:00).

Comment: The server time is UTC-0 and when the date is sent from angular, it is send as 2021-03-18 12:00:00 AM and in the server i receive this: 2021-03-17 10:00:00 PM

Comment: @RK001 And the change should be made on the server side?

Comment: If you want same date to be stored them handle it in API means convert it to your local time zone and then save

Comment: but saving in UTC format doesn't harm your application. because when you fetch it from UI it will automatically gets displayed as per your time zone. and this will give you more flexibility to implement multiple time zone support in future

Comment: Is there a way to change the default hour 12:00:00 AM that is sent from Angular? because i don't set this hour.. is default

Comment: I made some changes and now is working. I'm still sending the date with 2 hours behind but this is not a problem because the hour is not important. It is important that i dont send now the date at 12 am